# Login programmatically + remember me

Tags: php, symfony

When a user confirm its registration (a link sent in an email), I can log him manually like this (I don't like this code, but didn't found a better way to achieve this):

```
$user = $em->find(...);
$securityToken = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
$this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($securityToken);
```

My question : **I also need to set the remember-me cookie**, but I have no idea how to achieve this. I'm trying to figure out how authentication classes work in Symfony, but it's jungle out there :/

I know that Symfony generate a key (stored in a MySQL table), and then set a cookie, what should I use to reproduce the same behavior?

I'm not using any kind of external bundle, just Symfony.

Thx for any help!

Comment: What was your *exact* question?

Comment: My question : how can I set the remember-me cookie after login.

Comment: Are you using a user bundle?

Comment: @NoChecksum I'm not using any bundles, just the symfony basics.

Comment: Why don't you just redirect to your login page with the request parameters already filled in, including the _remember_me (or whatever name you gave it in the config)? This would avoid any hacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading again and again the Security component code, I found a way to log a user and set him the remember-me cookie. I don't like that kind of hack, if someone find a cleaner way I'll be happy to test it. I hope it can help someone, and I wish we will see one day a manual login helper in symfony.

```
// Replace "main" by the firewall name
$user = $em->find(...);
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());

// Find UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener and call the onSuccess method
$authenticationListener = null;
foreach ($this->get('security.firewall.map.context.main')->getContext()[0] as $listener) {
    if ($listener instanceof UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener) {
        $authenticationListener = $listener;
        break;
    }
}

if ($authenticationListener) {
    // The onSuccess method is private
    $onSuccessMethod = (new \ReflectionClass($authenticationListener))->getMethod('onSuccess');
    $onSuccessMethod->setAccessible(true);
    $response = $onSuccessMethod->invoke($authenticationListener, $request, $securityToken);

    // Do what you want with the response
}
```